# make javascript repeat for each row in a view

Tags: javascript, drupal, view

I have created a view in Drupal. I'm using JavaScript to modify the CSS in each row. The script runs on the first row, but does not make the changes on the rest of rows from the view.

This is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

window.onload = floatbr;

function floatbr() {

var f = document.getElementById('firstright') // Get div element
var s = document.getElementById('secondright') // Get div element
var w = document.getElementById('catwrapper') // Get div element
var sh = s.offsetHeight // secondright div height
var wh = w.offsetHeight // catwrapper div height
f.style.height = wh - sh + 'px'; }

</script>
```

I'm using it from this page: http://agsone.100webcustomers.com/floatbottom.php

having the script in the page once does not do the trick.
having the script in the view footer and repeating the script does not work.

The link to the jSfiddle with HTML, CSS and JavaScript is the following one:  http://jsfiddle.net/YTN3K/.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Better yet try to setup a http://jsfiddle.net page showing the issue.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without a sample of the markup of the rows you're trying to modify. Of course the quoted code doesn't modify more than one row, it's only applying the style information to a single element (the one element on the page with the `id` value "firstright").

Comment: @draevor: Both/and, linking to external sites like http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com *without* also quoting the relevant markup in the question is not useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. What markup to reference? I was talking about missing markup and suggested that she creates a page to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've added a link to the code in Fiddle. Its also the same as on this page http://agsone.100webcustomers.com/demo/bottom_float.html as described here: http://agsone.100webcustomers.com/floatbottom.php

Comment: @KathyChavez: Links to external sites like jsfiddle or 100webcustomers are a fine *adjunct* to your question, but *always* quote the relevant code/markup *in the question itself*. Stack Overflow is meant to be a resource for you now, **and** a resource for others with the same sort of question in the future. External pages can be modified, moved, deleted, etc., rendering the question and its answers completely useless for people in the future.

Comment: @draevor: And that's fine, but *just* putting it on jsfiddle or similar is not sufficient; it needs to be *in the question* as well. See my comment to Kathy above.

Comment: @KathyChavez: There are no "rows" in the jsfiddle page you linked. There are a couple of initial `div`s and then a `p`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - all the rows from the view are constructed the same way: WRapped in a div called catwrapper, then with a div called firstright, followed by a div called filler, then secondright. The body of the paragraph is in the catwrapper div AFTER all the other three divs.

I'll add more rows so you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/YTN3K/

Comment: I'll add more rows so you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/YTN3K/  (also added to the orig question)
Here you can see the additional rows and the first row has the "secondright" div in the bottom right corner. That is the object of this. But the 2nd and others don't are not affected by the js.

Comment: @KathyChavez: That may be the problem. You cannot have more than one element on a page with the same `id` value. So you cannot have a `div` with the `id` "catwrapper" and another element (of any kind) anywhere else on the page with the `id` "catwrapper". Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - good call. I tried changing the script to 

var f = document.getElementByClass('firstright') // Get div element

instead of getElementByID, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @KathyChavez: See my answer for some useful reference information and a couple of examples. `getElementByClass` isn't a DOM function. There's `getElementsByTagName` and, on *some* browsers but not others (in particular not older IE versions), there's `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal provides and already uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), so you should use it too. Drupal has its [own way to manage JavaScript](https://drupal.org/node/756722) and comes with some additional JavaScript API, mainly to handle passing variables from PHP to JavaScript properly, register script to run on page load and content addition, etc.

jQuery is well documented and popular, so finding documentation, tutorial and howto is easy. Its own [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) page is a good start. But it requires basic understanding of what an XHTML document is and how it is structured.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question and the markup you've linked to exactly what you're trying to do, so here's some general information to get you going:

The function you're currently using, `getElementById`, returns a *single* element: The one on the page with that `id` value. (`id` values **must** be unique on the page.)

To deal with multiple elements, you have several options. Two of the most popular:

- You can start with a given element and then use its `childNodes`, `firstChild`, `nextSibling`, and similar properties to navigate from it to other elements nearby.
- You can use `getElementsByTagName` (on the `document` or on an element) to find all elements within that container (including ones several levels down) that have a given tag. For instance, `document.getElementsByTagName("p")` gives you a `NodeList` of **all** paragraphs on the page.

These are properties and methods of the "DOM" (the Document Object Model), which is the tree of elements and associated information the browser creates when parsing and rendering your HTML.

References:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML bindings](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Specification's DOM info](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/#auto-toc-3)

Here's an example showing some very basic operations ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/oxosik)):

HTML:

```
<div id="justOneDiv">I'm the <code>justOneDiv</code> element. I'm unique on the page. JavaScript code on the page turned me red.</div>
<div id="container">I'm a container called "container" with <span>various</span> <code>span</code> elements. <span>Code</span> on the <span>page</span> has made all of the <code>span</code> elements in this container <span>bold</span>.</div>
<div>I'm a container with <span>various</span> <code>span</code> elements. <span>Note</span> that the <code>span</code> elements are <span>not</span> bold, because I'm <span>not</span> in the container above.</div>
<div>I'm a <code>div</code> with no class.</div>
<div class="foo">I'm a <code>div</code> with class "foo". Code on the page turned me blue.</div>
<div class="bar">I'm a <code>div</code> with class "bar". Code on the page turned me green.</div>
<div>Another classless <code>div</code></div>
<div class="foo other">Another "foo", also with class "other"</div>
<div class="bar">Another "bar"</div>
<div>Another classless <code>div</code></div>
<div class="foo">Another "foo"</div>
<div class="bar test">Another "bar", also with class "test"</div>
<div>Another classless <code>div</code></div>
<div class="foo">Another "foo"</div>
<div class="bar">Another "bar"</div>
<div>Another classless <code>div</code></div>
<div class="foo">Another "foo"</div>
<div class="bar">Another "bar"</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {

  hookEvent(window, "load", go);

  function go() {
    var list, index, div, container;

    // Get just the one element, turn it red
    document.getElementById("justOneDiv").style.color = "red";

    // Get the spans within the specific container
    container = document.getElementById("container");
    list = container.getElementsByTagName("span");

    // Loop through making those spans bold
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
      list.item(index).style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }

    // Get a NodeList of all divs on the page
    list = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    // Loop it, turning "foo"s blue and "bar"s green
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
      div = list.item(index);
      if (/\bfoo\b/.test(div.className)) {
        div.style.color = "blue";
      }
      else if (/\bbar\b/.test(div.className)) {
        div.style.color = "green";
      }
    }
  }

  function hookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
    // Very quick-and-dirty, recommend using a proper library,
    // this is just for the purposes of the example.
    if (typeof element.addEventListener !== "undefined") {
      element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }
    else if (typeof element.attachEvent !== "undefined") {
      element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
    }
    else {
      element["on" + eventName] = handler;
    }
  }
})();
```

---

Side note: The operations above can be made dramatically simpler by leveraging the utility functionality provided by any decent JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

For example, using that same HTML, here's the JavaScript code using jQuery for the same result ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/oxosik/2)):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Get just the one element, turn it red
  $("#justOneDiv").css("color", "red");

  // Get the spans within the specific container
  // Loop through making those spans bold
  $("#container span").css("font-weight", "bold");

  // Turn all divs with the class "foo" blue
  $("div.foo").css("color", "blue");

  // Turn all divs with the class "bar" green
  $("div.bar").css("color", "green");
});
```

The DOM is the official API; libraries like jQuery provide alternate or enhanced APIs. They're very useful and powerful, but I would recommend having some understanding of the DOM itself, even if you use a library and end up rarely writing code directly to the DOM API.